# Regex to match id values

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I want to find all the children of a `g` node with value of `id` attribute composed by:

```
a[number]-[one or more chars]

// examples:
//  - id="a1-a"
//  - id="a1-b"
//  - id="a1-abcd"
//  - id="a10-f"
//  - id="a0-z"
//  - id="b1-a" // not valid
//  - id="a1-2" // not valid
```

so I tried:

```js
const items = gElement.querySelectorAll(`[id^='a[0-9]+-[a-zA-Z]+']`)
```

But, it doesn't work.

Comment: You cant use RegExp in `querySelectorAll`, get all nodes and filter them by `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query selector, the pattern you're using (`[0-9]+`) is not being interpreted as a regular expression. Use the RegExp constructor to create a regular expression object from a string :

```js
const regex = new RegExp('^a[0-9]+-[a-zA-Z]+$');
const parentElement = document.querySelector('#parent-element');
const items = parentElement.querySelectorAll(`[id]`);
const children = Array.from(items).filter(item => regex.test(item.id));

console.log(children);
```

```html
<div id="parent-element">
  <p id="a1-a">Child 1</p>
  <p id="a1-b">Child 2</p>
  <p id="INVALID-1">Child 3</p>
  <p id="a10-f">Child 4</p>
  <p id="INVALID-2">Child 5</p>
  <p id="b1-a">Child 6</p>
  <p id="a1-2">Child 7</p>
</div>
```